# How to keep a link looking like it's "active" after it's clicked on

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

I have a menu and I want the link to that menu look like it's "active" after folks are taken to that page. Here is the code I have. Thanks so much!

```
a.menu:link {text-decoration:none;color:#B2B2B2;}
a.menu:visited {text-decoration:none;color:#B2B2B2;}
a.menu:hover {color:#FFFFFF;border-bottom: .5px solid #FF944D;}
a.menu:active {text-decoration:none;color:#FF944D;}


<a id="box" class="menu"  href="boxes.php">Boxes</a><br/>
<a id="bag" class="menu" href="bags">Bags</a><br/>
```

So when a user goes to the boxes.php page, the link will show its 'active' style. But when the user goes to the bags.php page, the "Boxes" link goes back to looking normal and the "Bags" link now shows its 'active' style. Many thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the current page differently in the main navigation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730385/how-to-style-the-current-page-differently-in-the-main-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

The (2nd) easiest way will be to use jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $(".menu").click( function() {
        $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        $( this ).addClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

Now we need to remake the css for our js:

```
.menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: B2B2B2;
}

.menu:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #FF944D;
}

.clicked {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF944D;
}
```

This should hopefully work to get rid of your annoying problem.

An alternate *super super* easy way will be to add this to your links on their respective pages:

```
style="text-decoration:none;color:#FF944D"
```

So on your page `boxes.php` your html looks like this:

```
<a id="box" class="menu"  href="boxes.php" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FF944D">Boxes</a><br/>
<a id="bag" class="menu" href="bags">Bags</a><br/>
```

And on `bags(.php?)` it looks like this:

```
<a id="bag" class="menu" href="boxes.php">Boxes</a><br/>
<a id="box" class="menu"  href="bags" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FF944D">Bags</a><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I'm afraid it didn't work. the links remain the same and do not become the 'clicked' style.

Comment: Even with the second method?

Comment: Sent comment without thinking, the CSS will probably override the `style` attribut

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't see the second method but just saw your other comment about the CSS overriding the 'style' attribute. The other thing is that the menu is set as <?php incluclude  ?> on each page. I am hoping for a solution that does not require repeating the menu on each individual page and manually overriding on each page. Crossing my fingers!